# Error when serializing xml to object because of inner attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

The error is:

There was an error deserializing the object of type Releye.Solution.Nordnet.ExternalService.AggregatedCustomerInfoJson. End element 'availableForTrading' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'curr' from namespace ''.

I suspect that it has something to do with the tag "availableForTrading" (and a copule of more attributes) have the "inner attribute" of "curr=SEK".

I don't know how to handle this properly. Any advice appreciated.

My class looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class AccountSummaryItem
{
    public AccountSummaryItem()
    {
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "userMapping")]
    public List<UserMappingItem> usermappings { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string accno { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int? atyid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string category { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string minor { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string deceased { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "riskEstimate")]
    public RiskEstimate RiskEstimate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string amlCustomerInfoUpdateNeeded { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "availableForTrading", IsRequired = false)]
    public string availableForTrading { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "availableForWithdrawal", IsRequired = false)]
    public string availableForWithdrawal { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool blocked { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "ownCapital", IsRequired = false)]
    public string ownCapital { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "pawnValue", IsRequired = false)]
    public string pawnValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool shareville { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string totalValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string atycode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string chgid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string chgname { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool hasCreditAgreement { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool hasTrustee { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ofcid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ofcname { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string regdate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string role { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string roleDescription { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

The xml looks like this:

```
<accountSummary>
<amlCustomerInfoUpdateNeeded>false</amlCustomerInfoUpdateNeeded>
<availableForTrading curr="SEK">269061.14</availableForTrading>
<availableForWithdrawal curr="SEK">10921.14</availableForWithdrawal>
<blocked>false</blocked>
<deceased>false</deceased>
<minor>false</minor>
<ownCapital curr="SEK">1152082.20718864</ownCapital>
<pawnValue curr="SEK">0.0</pawnValue>
<totalValue curr="SEK">10921.14</totalValue>
<accno>11245381213</accno>
<atycode>Depåkonton</atycode>
<atyid>108</atyid>
<category>OWNER</category>
<chgid>131476</chgid>
<chgname>SE PRB</chgname>
<hasTrustee>false</hasTrustee>
<ofcid>122</ofcid>
<ofcname>PRB</ofcname>
<regdate>1998-08-18</regdate>
</accountSummary>
```

Comment: I think your suspicion is correct. Try copying your XML, creating a new #C class and then clicking "Edit" -> "Paste Special" -> "Paste XML As Classes" and see if you can work with that.

Comment: If you want to ignore `curr="SEK"` then you can preprocess xml-files (open, load, find/replace) before deserialization.

Comment: Can you post the serializing code?

Answer (score 0):

I found an acceptable solution.
By adding a class representing this attribute in the following manner:

```
[DataContract]
public class AccountSummary_ownCapital
{
    public AccountSummary_ownCapital()
    {
    }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "$")]
    public double ownCapital { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string curr { get; set; }
}
```

And then changing my "old" class to (for the specific attributes containing the inner "curr"):

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public AccountSummary_ownCapital ownCapital { get; set; }
```

Then I get this nice custom object containing both the value for the curr-attribute and the value for the "ownCapital".